# Adding dimension to numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Why is the following code not adding a third dimension to the matrix and how should I change the code to get what I need?

```
imm = np.zeros(shape=(10,10))
dims = imm.shape
if len(dims) < 3:
    imm.reshape((dims[0], dims[1], 1))
imm.shape # I want this to pring (10,10,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to change the dimensions of an array, as long as the product of the sizes in the new dimensions remains the same as it was for the old.

In all cases but one, the reshaping operation returns a new array object, but uses the same underlying data in memory. This means that reshaping is very cheap, even for enormous arrays. You just have to assign the returned reference back to the original array.

The only way to reshape the array object in place is to assign to its [`shape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) property:

```
arr.shape += (1,)
```

All the other methods to add a dimension return a new array object. In *most* cases, they will not copy the data, unless you do something weird with the indexing scheme:

1. Use [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

   ```
   arr = np.reshape(arr, arr.shape + (1,))
   ```
2. Use [`arr.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape). This works exactly like `np.reshape`:

   ```
   arr = arr.reshape(arr.shape + (1,))
   ```
3. Index the array with [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) (a.k.a. `None`):

   ```
   arr = arr[..., np.newaxis]
   ```

   OR

   ```
   arr = arr[..., None]
   ```

   This creates a new array object, inserting a new axis of size 1 into your indexing scheme wherever you put the `newaxis` object, but leaves the underlying data untouched.
4. Use [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html). This will insert a new dimension of size 1 wherever you tell it to through the second argument:

   ```
   arr = np.expand_dims(arr, -1)
   ```
5. For your particular case, you can use [`np.atleast_3d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_3d.html#numpy.atleast_3d):

   ```
   arr = np.atleast_3d(arr)
   ```

   This function behaves strangely when given a 1D input: it places the dimensions of size one in the beginning and the end of the tuple, instead of all on one side. The 2D case behaves exactly as you want though.
6. Use [`np.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) to explicitly create a new array object with the expected number of dimensions:

   ```
   arr = np.array(arr, copy=False, ndmin=3)
   ```

   `copy=False` must be stated explicitly to avoid copying the data. The third axis will be *prepended* to the shape, not appended, so you may need to do something like

   ```
   arr = np.moveaxis(arr, 0, -1)
   ```

   This is by far the least desirable option for your particular needs.

**Update**

If we equate your original problem to a thumbtack, here is the nuclear sledgehammer of a solution:

```
arr = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, arr.shape + (1,))
```

Just remember that [`as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) really is a nuclear sledgehammer!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to add a dimension to a numpy array is

```
imm = imm[..., np.newaxis]
```

Don't worry, this isn't doing any expensive copying or anything, the underlying memory remains in place*. All that happens is the  `ndim` increases by 1.

I think this solution is cleaner as you don't have to worry about grabbing the `shape` and putting it into `reshape`. It also has the advantage of you can quickly put the `newaxis` in any dimension. Say you wanted dimension 0 or 1 to be the new dimension

```
imm = imm[np.newaxis, ...]  # new dimension is axis 0
imm = imm[:, np.newaxis, :] # new dimension is axis 1
imm = imm[:, :, np.newaxis] # new dimension is axis 2 (same as above)
```

---

* you can prove this to yourself by doing

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = x[..., np.newaxis]
x *= 10
print(y)
# 
# [[10]
#  [20]
#  [30]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
new_imm = np.expand_dims(imm,axis=-1)
```

and 
reshape doesn't work in place. Your code isn't working because you aren't assigning the value returned by reshape to any variable.

Answer (score 1):

`imm.reshape` does not performs inplace modification. Instead it returns the modified array.

Hence, do `imm = imm.reshape((dims[0], dims[1], 1))` and you will get the desired output. Consider reading the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way if you want to modify `imm` in place:

```
import numpy as np
imm = np.zeros(shape=(10,10))
dims = imm.shape
if len(dims) < 3:
    imm.shape = imm.shape + (1,)
print(imm.shape) 
# (10,10,1)
```

You could use

```
imm.shape = imm.shape + (1,)
```

Or simply,

```
imm.shape += 1,
```